# mysql search using a keyword table... best approach

Tags: mysql, search, keyword

I'm writing an alerts system for users in an auction.  i need to build a list of users with a list of auction lots that match their keywords.
I have a users table with several thousand rows, each user can have multiple keywords from a second table.  i need to search a auction lots table (title & body) for all these keywords, there are several thousand lots....

whats the best approach with the least number of queries?

```
CREATE TABLE `auction_lots` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `search` (`body`,`title`)
);

CREATE TABLE `user_accounts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `firstname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `user_keywords` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
);
```

i'm thinking... 2 queries, get all keywords, get all lots that match all keywords then use PHP to build a list of the user lots
or use subqueries in some clever way?!

what do u think?

many thanks,

rob.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.title, t2.keyword, t3.id, t3.firstname, t3.lastname, t3.email, count(t1.id) AS count 

FROM auction_lots t1 

INNER JOIN user_keywords AS t2 ON 

( t1.body LIKE CONCAT(  '%', t2.keyword,  '%' ) ) 

INNER JOIN user_accounts AS t3 ON 

t2.user_id = t3.id 

WHERE t3.is_active = 1 

group by t2.keyword, t2.user_id 

order by t2.user_id
```

How did you get on with this problem?

I have the same data and task, different industry. I've come up with the above so far, I transformed it to suit your data, but it will only join one field t1.body and performance is not so good when benchmarked against tables with thousands of rows. Any better solutions and I'm all ears...